# Shiny: Filtering not working as well as download

Tags: r, shiny

I have this very simple app where I have a data frame containing one grouping variable and a value column. By default, the app should display the data without filtering. The user should be able to filter the dataframe and save/download the filtered data frame in a csv/excel file. The filtering and download isn't working. I have the following code,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

state <- c("CA", "CA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "CA")
total <- c(100, 111, 120, 130, 11, 200)
dataf <- data.frame(state, total)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Output data"),
      selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Stat",
                  choices = c("All", "CA", "PA"),
                  selected = "All"),
      sliderInput("total", "Total Number",
                  value = c(mean(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE), max(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  min = min(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE),
                  max = max(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE)),
      
      downloadButton(outputId = "download_data", label = "Download"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    dataf %>%
      filter(total == input$total)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    dataf
  )
}

output$download_data <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "download_data.csv",
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(df, file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

A little guide to solve the problems would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the updated code below

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

state <- c("CA", "CA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "CA")
total <- c(100, 111, 120, 130, 11, 200)
dataf <- data.frame(state, total)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Output data"),
      selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Stat",
                  choices = c("CA", "PA"),
                  selected = " "),
      sliderInput("total", "Total Number",
                  value = c(mean(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE), max(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE)),
                  min = min(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE),
                  max = max(dataf$total, na.rm = TRUE)),
      h5(''),
      downloadButton(outputId = "downloadData", label = "Download"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- reactive({
    dataf %>%
      filter(total %in% c(input$total[1]:input$total[2]), state == input$state)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    df()
  )

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("download_data", ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(df(), file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```